# Suspicious call to 'LinkedHashMap.get'

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Hello I have the following code

```java
public static LinkedHashMap<Object, String[]> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public static void parseDataset(int line){
  String[] dataArr = dataMap.get(dataMap.keySet().toArray()[line]);
}
```

Since the Object I use as a Key is dynamically generated I have no knowledge about it so I have to find it before I can use it to get its value.

This code gives me the warning **Suspicious call to 'LinkedHashMap.get'**, is that a problem and how would I get rid of the warning?

Comment: `Since the Object I use as a Key is dynamically generated I have no knowledge about it` - if you have no knowledge about it, how do you know that it properly overrides `equals` and `hashCode`? If it doesn't, you shouldn't use it as a key in a `HashMap`.

Comment: @Eran For this specific part of the code I dont always have the knowledge about it, I do override equals and hashcode for a different part of my code.

Comment: Just to answer *why is that a problem?* Because `LinkedHashMap.get()` has O(n) complexity when other implementations have O(1) or O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `get`: instead of converting the keys to an array, use `values()` instead. This works because `values()` iterates in the same order as the corresponding `keys()`:

```
String[] dataArr = (String[]) dataMap.values().toArray()[line];
```

But you don't need to use `toArray()` either, which wastefully allocates an array containing all values, from which you only want one: you can just iterate through the values to get the thing you want:

```
static String[] nthItem(int n) {
  int i = 0;
  for (String[] value : dataMap.values()) {
    if (i == n) return value;
    ++i;
  }
  throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
```

Or:

```
String[] dataArr = dataMap.values().stream().skip(line).findFirst().orElseThrow();
```

(Existing implementations of this sort of thing can be found in commonly-used libraries, e.g. [Guava's `Iterables.get`](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get-java.lang.Iterable-int-))

Comment: If `get` cannot be used reliably, `LinkedHashMap` shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: values() returns the Object that is the key instead of the Array, which would be the value and what I want to get.

Comment: @oneandonlyk so the method named `values()` returns the key?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes if I write it like the first example Code.

Comment: @oneandonlyk does `keySet()` return a `Set` of values for you then? :)

Comment: @Kayaman No the `keySet()` by itself only returns a `Set` of my Keys, if you want to hint to me using the values inside my `get` it will still be the same warning.

Comment: `String[] dataArr = (String[]) dataMap.values().toArray()[line];` this does give me the Array instead of an Object.

Comment: @oneandonlyk just because it wasn't cast to its actual type and was an `Object` reference doesn't mean it was the key. The keys aren't of actual `Object` types either (I hope, since that wouldn't make any sense), but subclasses. You're just using `Object` because, well I'm assuming you don't know any better.

Comment: @Kayaman I am using Object to simplify but yes I didnt check the Output before answering, just saw the errormessage and didnt think about it.